# How to automatically set first line of paragraph (in a cell) as a heading

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a large table with about 1000 rows in Word. I'm looking to make a table of contents, which requires each of the cells to have a heading style.

The table has 2 columns, and I'm looking to set the first line of each row of that table to have a heading style. Is there an automatic way of doing this? I've been trying manually and it's going to take many hours.

EDIT: Unfortunately when I exported from excel, all of the "new paragraphs" actually became linebreaks, as opposed to paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by line you mean the first paragraph in each cell, in the first column.

You can use a macro to do this:

```
Sub setTableHeadings() 
Dim tbl as Table
if Selection.Tables.Count=1 Then
Set tbl=Selection.Tables(1)
Dim rw as Row
For Each rw in tbl.Rows
 rw.Cells(1).Range.Text = Replace(rw.Cells(1).Range.Text, Chr(11), Chr(13), , 1)
rw.Cells(1).Range.Paragraphs(1).Style="Heading 1"
Next
End If
End Sub
```

This loops through each row, the first column, and applies the Heading 1 style to the first paragraph in the cell.

In a copy of your document (just in case), select the table and run the macro to update the first column.

EDIT:  Updated to replace 1st manual line feed in cell with paragraph mark, and then can apply style to just that first paragraph (note Chr(11) is the manual line feed character if used ALT ENTER in Excel to create line breaks).

Comment: Hey Tanya, that's very very nearly perfect.Unfortunately since I exported from excel all the paragraph markers are actually line breaks. I tried to mess around with getting genuine paragraph markers into excel but couldn't see how to do it.

Is there a way to use the same macro but change Paragraphs(1) to work with line breaks. 

I did a bit of googling and couldn't find anything that seemed useful, but I have 0 experience with VB so may have missed something.

Thanks again

Comment: For clarification, would be vbLf (line feed, ASCII 10) according to https://www.oakleys.org.uk/blog/2017/05/how_to_insert_new_line_line_break_in_microsoft_word_using_vba since I used CHAR(10) in excel.

Comment: Hi Daniel, see modification above with extra line of code that replaces just first manual line break with paragraph mark so you can then apply style to just that first paragraph.  You may need to modify from Chr(11) to Chr(10) - I just did a test of copying and pasting from Excel into Word as a table after using ALT ENTER to create line breaks within the Excel cell.